# how can get Active User Rate in flurry

Tags: android, flurry

Ratio of the number of app users to the total number of downloads. Helps you understand if you are gaining or losing your audience over time.

Comment: Have you tried checking out google play developer console?

Comment: NO, can we get this through flurry

Comment: @Derek can we get this through flurry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to the Usage -> Retention section for this type of analysis.

The retention section is composed of two different metrics. The first will tell you what % of your app users remain active x days after install. You can get daily level retention from this chart.

The second metric is 'rolling retention' and this will tell you historically what percentage of your users remain active up to 30 days after installing the app.

[image]